# speech to text for multiple language

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I am working on speech recognition, i need to do this with multiple languages.

what i exactly want if user talk in hindi or any other language, then need to display it on text View. 
Right now its working perfectly for English.

what i need to do it for multiple language as per user choice..

please help me out, thank you..

here is my code

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;
private TextView mVoiceInputTv;
private ImageButton mSpeakBtn;
private TextToSpeech t1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mVoiceInputTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.voiceInput);
    mSpeakBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    mSpeakBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startVoiceInput();
        }
    });
}

private void startVoiceInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Hello, How can I help you?");
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {

    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                if(userlanguage.equals("English")){
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                else if(userlanguage.equals("Hindi")){
                    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/DroidHindi.ttf");
                    mVoiceInputTv.setTypeface(face);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                else if(userlanguage.equals("Marathi")){
                    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Marathi.ttf");
                    mVoiceInputTv.setTypeface(face);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
                else if(userlanguage.equals("Gujarati")){
                    face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Gujarati.ttf");
                    mVoiceInputTv.setTypeface(face);
                    mVoiceInputTv.setText(result.get(0));
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i did something like this but i dint no is this right way or not?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. you need to change your locale according to language selection
     intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, **Locale.CHINESE**);

Step 2. Save the speech text into string file. and use getString method. In this way you can use string according to language.

[image]

this code can be used to fetch different languge string from different values folder..

```
    Configuration conf = getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = new Locale("pl");
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    Resources resources = new Resources(getAssets(), metrics, conf);
    String str = resources.getString(id);
```

Comment: i got speech text string but also need to print that as per user laguage, for ex if user talks in chinese then while printing on label also want chinese only.currently showing in english only.

Comment: Yes you need to add different values folder for different languages for that and use getString(R.string.speechText)

Comment: but here i need to set some string in different language in each folder right?
i don't want this.whatever user talk i need to print that one.@ Harmindar Singh

Answer (score 0):

Google's servers currently support English, Mandarin Chinese, and Japanese. The web search model is available in all three languages, while free-form has primarily been optimized for English.

Set the value for EXTRA_LANGUAGE. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_LANGUAGE

Answer (score 0):

You will create different activity for different Language ....

Ex: suppose you select Hindi Language ,Now it will go to Hindi language Activity.. as like this....

Code :

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US");
```

Another Activity:

```
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "hi");
```

i hope this will work...

Answer (score 0):

whichLang is a spinner index. For TTS ->

```js
when (whichLang) {
               CustomEnums.LANG_TR.value -> tts.language =  Locale("tr", "TR")
               CustomEnums.LANG_EN.value -> tts.language =  Locale("en", "US")
               CustomEnums.LANG_GE.value -> tts.language =  Locale("de", "DE")
               CustomEnums.LANG_FR.value -> tts.language =  Locale("fr", "FR")
               CustomEnums.LANG_IT.value -> tts.language =  Locale("ar", "SA")
           }
```

For Speech to Text ->

```js
 when(whichLang){
                CustomEnums.LANG_TR.value-> intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "tr-TR")
                CustomEnums.LANG_EN.value-> intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "en-US")
                CustomEnums.LANG_GE.value-> intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "de-DE")
                CustomEnums.LANG_FR.value-> intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "fr-FR")
                CustomEnums.LANG_IT.value-> intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, "ar-SA")
            }
```

Have Fun!